# With email parameter , which ends with dot com, can't get Result from Restful Web Service by using Perl LWP

Tags: perl, rest

I want to use perl with Module `LWP` to get the XML info from Restful Webservice.

Here is the Code:

```
my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;

$ua->proxy(['http','https'],'http://proxy:3128');
$ua->default_header('Accept-Charset'=>'utf-8');
$ua->default_header('Accept'=>'application/*********; version=1');

my $url= 'https://user:password@mailbox.********.net/mailboxes/?emailaddress=name@domain.net';

print Dumper($ua->get($url));
```

It works always good for all the email address like `.eu`, `.org` or `.net`, except for the email address ends with `.com`. (For example: `name@domail.com`)

The error message is:

```
The following error was encountered while trying to retrieve the URL:
    https://user@mailbox.******.net/mailboxes/?

Access Denied.

Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. 
Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.

Your cache administrator is *****@**.**
```

The corresponded Response HEAD:

```
 '_headers' => bless( {
                                    'connection' => 'close',
                                    'client-response-num' => 1,
                                    'date' => 'Wed, 19 Nov 2014 15:53:45 GMT',
                                    'x-squid-error' => 'ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0',
                                    'client-peer' => '****:3128',
                                    'content-length' => '3502',
                                    'client-date' => 'Wed, 19 Nov 2014 15:53:45 GMT',
                                    'content-type' => 'text/html',
                                    'mime-version' => '1.0',
                                    'title' => 'ERROR: The requested URL could not be retrieved',
                                    'server' => 'squid/3.1.12',
                                    'x-cache' => 'MISS from proxy',
                                    'x-cache-lookup' => 'NONE from proxy:3128'
                                  }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
```

I have tested with SoapUI and curl, they didn't meet this problem. That means `.com` works also with SoapUI and cuil. Only in perl with LWP, it gets problem.
Anyway when I added a dummy parameter like
 `https://**/mailboxes/?emailaddress=name@domain.com&foo=bar` at the end of the link, it works.

I have no idea, if it's a bug in LWP or maybe some incompatible issue between LWP and Proxy Setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Access Denied.

Access control configuration prevents your request from being allowed at this time. 
Please contact your service provider if you feel this is incorrect.
...
'x-squid-error' => 'ERR_ACCESS_DENIED 0',
```

There is an ACL in the proxy you use which denies your request.
If you have access to the proxy configuration check there, otherwise contact you cache administrator with your problem.

Comment: I have tried with SoapUI and Curl, they didn't met this problem. If it is the proxy problem, why could these software or command get the xml info, which use the same proxy.

Comment: There might be an ACL based on the User-Agent. Try to change it.

Comment: Thank you， I'll try to communicate with the IT department about it tomorrow, to find out the cause of the problem.